# refresh Cells with AG grid With react use cellRenderer and another component function

Tags: reactjs, datatables, grid, ag-grid

refresh Cells with AG grid With react use cellRenderer and another component function ...

I use AG grid to make grid in my website and need to refresh cells after update or delete function in my component

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'

const gotoproject = (p, { refreshcell }) => {
  var projectid = p.data.project.id
  let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  var adminid = user.id
  console.log(p)

  function getProjectid() {
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Origin: '',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        AdminID: adminid,
      }),
    }
    fetch(
      'https://project.com/api/approved/' +
        projectid,
      options,
    )
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(function (resJson) {
        return resJson
      })
  }

  async function deleteproject() {
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Origin: '',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        AdminID: adminid,
      }),
    }
    await fetch(
      'https://project.com/api/delete/' +
        projectid,
      options,
    )
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(function (resJson) {
        return resJson
      })
    p.api.refreshCells()
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button className="buttoninview" onClick={getProjectid}>
        view
      </button>
      <button className="buttoninedit" onClick={getProjectid}>
        approve
      </button>
      <button className="buttonindelete" onClick={deleteproject}>
        refus
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
const gettime = (p) => {
  var date = new Date(p.data.project.CrateDateTime)
  var year = date.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' })
  var month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: '2-digit' })
  var day = date.toLocaleString('default', { day: '2-digit' })
  var hour = date.toLocaleString('default', { h: '2-digit' })
  var minute = date.toLocaleString('default', { minute: '2-digit' })

  var formattedDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year
  return hour
}
const gettimeedited = (p) => {
  var date = new Date(p.data.project.UpdateDateTime)
  var year = date.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' })
  var month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: '2-digit' })
  var day = date.toLocaleString('default', { day: '2-digit' })
  var hour = date.toLocaleString('default', { h: '2-digit' })
  var minute = date.toLocaleString('default', { minute: '2-digit' })

  var formattedDate =
    day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' | ' + hour + ' : ' + minute + ' '
  return hour
}

export default function DataGridDemo(refreshcell) {
  const [projects, getProjects] = useState([])
  const rowData = projects

  async function getProjectsfun() {
    let result = await fetch(
      'https://project.com/api/view/all',
    )
    result = await result.json()
    getProjects(result)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getProjectsfun()
  }, [])

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'project.id',
      headerName: 'project number',
      filter: true,
      maxWidth: 200,
      sortable: true,
    },
    // Using dot notation to access nested property
    {
      field: 'project.ProjectNameAR',
      headerName: 'project name',
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'project',
      headerName: ' ',
      cellRenderer: gotoproject,
      minWidth: 300,
    },
  ]
  function refreshcell() {
    getProjectsfun()
  }
  // var t = setInterval(refreshcell, 3000)
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className="CRMPAGE"
        initial={{ width: '0' }}
        animate={{ width: '100%' }}
        exit={{ x: window.innerWidth, transaction: { duration: 0.1 } }}
      >
        {projects ? (
          <>
            <div>
              <div style={{ height: '90vh' }} className="ag-theme-alpine">
                {/* <DataGrid columns={columns} rowHeight={rowHeight} rows={rows} /> */}
                <AgGridReact
                  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%;' }}
                  rowData={rowData}
                  enableRtl={true}
                  columnDefs={columnDefs}
                  animateRows={true}
                  rowSelection={'multiple'}
                ></AgGridReact>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {/* <DataGrid columns={columns} rowHeight={rowHeight} rows={rows} /> */}
            <div>
              <div style={{ height: '90vh' }} className="ag-theme-alpine">
                {/* <DataGrid columns={columns} rowHeight={rowHeight} rows={rows} /> */}
                <AgGridReact
                  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%;' }}
                  rowData={rowData}
                  enableRtl={true}
                  columnDefs={columnDefs}
                  animateRows={true}
                  rowSelection={'multiple'}
                ></AgGridReact>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </motion.div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**I try to make it by ag-grid api but it's didnt work wih me ~**
please help me to refresh it without .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2W0G.png)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to AG Grid, there are many ways to refresh cells.

One way to refresh cells inside the grid is to [replace the data you gave it](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-row-data/) with a fresh set of data.

For this to work correctly, you need to enable immutable data by providing id's to your rows and setting the [getRowId](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids) callback in the grid option

```
<AgGridReact 
...
getRowId={(params) => params.data.yourId}
...
></AgGridReact>
```

rowData = [{...someData, yourId: 0}, {...someData, yourId: 1}]

This way grid will refresh only the cells with new data, provided the field is the same as in the column definitions.

if This does not work for you, you can always call [redraw rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-refresh-redrawRows) and pass the node of the row to rerender or just refresh all rows.

Comment: i didn't need replace data in my graid , i need to refresh data after delete or edit in cells by "cellRenderer" out function component

Comment: I am already have an function make refresh in cells but i can't use it by another component !